# what's the suggested doc/tutorial/url for database schema design

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

want to learn details about how to do a better database design
any suggested recommended for this topic? 
thx very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a vendor-neutral intro course online:

- [Database Design from the ground up](http://databases.about.com/cs/specificproducts/a/designmenu.htm)

And here are two book recommendations:

- [Database Design for Mere Mortals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840) - highly recommended!
- [Beginning Database Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470385499)

Comment: +1 I have heard alot of good thing about Database Design for Mere Mortals

Comment: marc_s: When I click on part 1 of "DB design from the ground up" I see this: "Microsoft Access is one of the most popular database platforms on the market today. This series of articles helps you get started with Access." :( Then I read "What is a database" which says: "Just like Excel tables, database tables consist of columns and rows." No one who is serious about learning database design should waste a moment reading such rubbish.

Comment: @dportas: it gets better after the first page :-9

Comment: thx on this, besides amazon books, is there any suggested web site / free tutorial/ pdf on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a tutorial on database design at http://www.databaseapplications.com.au/design.jsp  It deals with table design and normalization up to and including third normal form and all relationships between tables.  It uses an example database for explanation.  An entity-relationship diagram is shown and the sql code to create the sample database is downloadable.  It is vendor neutral.

Answer (score 0):

What database do you intend to use and what is it going to be used for i.e what kind of application is going to use it?

Answers to these questions effect the design.

Comment: i use oracle 10g and mysql 5.1

Answer (score 0):

[Terry Halpin, Information Modeling and Relational Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123735688)

[Fabian Pascal, Practical Issues in Database Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485559)